# obtaining a vector from another vector

Tags: r

I have a vector,

```
x<-c(1,3,2,3,1,4,2,1,3,4,2,1,0,2,4,5,2,1,2)
```

I would like to obtain a vector of x by not including one every other time starting from the first element up to the 10th element. This will be to include elements (1,3,5,7 and 9 of x)  to obtain (1,2,1,2,3). In line with the below expression which produces an error.

```
x[1:10,by=2]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
x[seq(1, 10, by=2)]
```

In this way with `seq(1, 10, by=2)` you generate the indexes of x - elements and then you get them from `x` with `[]` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way could do this, although the above suggestions are more straight forward

```
x[1:10%%2 != 0][1:5]
```

Similar way (probably better) suggested by @SimonO'Hanlon

```
x[c(TRUE, FALSE)][1:5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
x[seq(from=1,to=10, by=2)]
```